# Write a database change to another database via JMS

Tags: database, oracle, jms

Is there anyway to write one database(Oracle) change to another database(Oracle) via JMS?

Thanks

Comment: what do you meant by changes ? you want to keep DB in sync like master /slave. OR you want only to note down change happening in other DB like "user A" created "Table_A" . In either doing JMS is not  the right approach.

Comment: Thanks Ramki, It is master/slave db.

Comment: Say I have one db call db1 and there is table call tb1. I need to populate changes in tb1 to db2 tb1. And if JMS is not the right approach, which approach can I use??

Comment: So you need some kind of logical master/slave replication between Oracle databases without paying GoldenGate license? I'm afraid you question is too broad and are are many ways how to implement this. Even if you insist on using Java and JMS. PS: In case of Weblogic look at Oracle AQ(Advanced Queuing) it's Oracle's implementation of messaging system which can act as JMS provider(RA).

Comment: As a starter you can read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17516/tdpii_intro2ii.htm#TDPII006

Comment: Thanks ibre5041. Yes exactly. It is a kind of master/slave replication. Since already existing system is using jboss, jms and java I have to use those. Any best way to implement my requirement??

Comment: HI Asha ,  Jboss, JMS, Java are middle tire component its not easy to implement ( = near to impossible ) using these tools. Take some simple case  if your updating a single row, and JMS failed in this case . then what you do? rollback master transaction.  you have to ensure all your transacation is written in both master & slave. if not it will not be useful . that's why you need "GoldenGate" .

Comment: You can tell why you need master/slave ? GEO redundancy , or as Backup solution , if Master is down then slave to be active.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Java program that uses "Database Change Notification" to be notified when db1.tb1 is changed to then apply the same change into db2.